# use mariadb to store future market data (large number records)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

for future market data, we need at least 1,000,000 records each day, each record has less them 10 fileds with a few letters. i chose mariadb 5.5 on centos 7. engine is innodb. my.cnf has following configure:

```
[server]
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```

when i insert records, it is not so fast, but it can be accepted. but when I do export data, it is very slow when innodb talbe large than some GB. 
fields like: id, bid, ask, time, xx,xx, id is auto increment, and is the key. my query sql like following:
select * from table where instrument="xx" and time >= "xx" and time <= "xx"

any advise how to speed up select performance?  thanks!

Comment: If you need to handle a really big quantity of statements and they need to stay fast you should look at implementing something like Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ also your question doesn't really have that much information, like what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Index the columns you're `WHERE`ing against, get a bigger server, etc.

Comment: @StrahBehry in my case, i used mysql/mariadb to store data. the data is like: id:1, instrumentid: lme-cu, tradingday: 20160321 ask:33.33 bid:33.30 askvolume:1 bidvolume:2. All information is small string or integer. my issue is, when i have more than 100,000,000 records, the database with my sql query will very slow. mostly to query a 10000 records, it would cost more than 3 minutes. i have read it may caused by full text index since i used compare syntax in  `where` , i want if there has any tips to improve database performance that query. thanks.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, i will try to create index and find if it can help speed up select. thanks, very useful comments!

Comment: Solr would actually fix that,  it works as a layer between your database and you will be querying solr instead of the database, it can turn queries that take minutes into a few seconds http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html might be worth to give a shot. Since it already costs more than 3 minutes I doubt making it indexed will speed it up enough.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks both. when i create a 'where' field index, it is very helpful. time cost from 4mins to several seconds. amazing improvement. Thanks! Also i will try to have a look for solr.

Answer (score 0):

To tailor to the `SELECT`, make the table InnoDB and set up the clustered `PRIMARY KEY` so that the desired rows are consecutive.  This is likely to slow down the `INSERT` process, but that is not an issue -- 12 inserts/second is easily handled.

But let me digress for a moment -- do the 1M rows come in all at once?  Or are the trickling in over 7 hours?  Or what?  If all at once, sort the data according to the PK before doing the massive `LOAD DATA`.

Your query begs for `PRIMARY KEY(instrument, time)`.  But a PK must be "unique"; is that unique?  If not, then another column (`id`?)` should be tacked onto the end to make it unique.

Note that if it is unique, then you don't need an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; get rid of it.  For such large tables, minimizing the number of indexes is critical, not just for performance, but for even being able to survive.

Other things to do...

- Normalize the instrument.  That have a table of such and map it to an id, probably `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes) if there are under 65K.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) for more discussion of normalizing as you ingest.
- Shrink any fields you can -- `FLOAT` (4 bytes) is tempting, but it has round off errors.  `DECIMAL` is tricky because you need to worry about penny-stocks at one extreme and BRK-A at the other.
- Look at the rest of the queries to make sure this change in PK does not hurt them.
- Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* RAM (assuming you have more than 4GB of RAM).
- If you do have to keep `id` as an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then add `INDEX(id)`; that is all that is needed to keep A_I happy.
- Use `CHARACTER SET ascii` unless you need utf8 somewhere.
- `Volume` can exceed 4 billion in rare cases; ponder what to do.
- Fetching 10K rows in PK order will take only seconds.
- `FULLTEXT` is not useful for this application.
- `PARTITIONing` is not likely to be useful; we can revisit it if you care to share the rest of the queries.  On the other hand, if you will be deleting 'old' data, then `PARTITIONing` is an excellent idea.  See [my partition blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: rick, thanks so much for your suggestion and tips. when i do index for instrument+tradingday, it seems improve more fast, from 4mins -> several seconds. another case i wanna to figure out is that innodb table increase so fast, each month, i see at least 2GB increased. so i think about to move all old data to archive engine. but archive table cannot be indexed, that is a problem if i want to query data in that archive table.

Comment: That one query you mentioned will run _almost_ as fast even after a year's worth of data has been added.